# Is there a Python-based library or code that calculates Gaussian curvature?

Tags: python, 3d, gaussian, feature-extraction

I have generated point cloud data and mesh data in .ply formats. From either of the .ply files, I want to use the (X,Y,Z) coordinates to calculate Gaussian curvature. I have looked into the math, but it seems too complicated to code from scratch given the short amount of time I have.

Is there an existing Python-based library or tutorial that calculates Gaussian curvature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hace mesh data, you can use [pymesh](https://github.com/qnzhou/PyMesh) to compute Gaussian curvature of the surface:

```
mesh = pymesh.load_mesh("your_mesh.ply")
mesh.add_attribute("vertex_gaussian_curvature")
```

Tales a look at the docs for more info.

Comment: Hello David...thanks for the answer. However, are there other ways except for PyMesh or libigl? I am trying to avoid large and complicated libraries if possible.